# User profile updates password even if not filled (Theme my login) in Firefox?

Tags: users, profiles

I'm using Theme My Login plugin. It works fine, besides this case, only in Firefox.
Updating user profile change password even if password field has not been filled, resulting in the impossibility to access the user account anymore. Any hint?

I think it could be linked with firefox ignoring "autocomplete=off" on password field but i am not sure and don't know how to avoid this behaviour.

Edit: Confirm that in anonymous mode this does not happen and can be solved with an hack, that is including a fake field before password field, so that firefox fill that instead that the real one

```
< input type="password" style="display: none" id="fakePassword" name="fakePassword" value="" />
```

Any idea of a cleaner solution?